# Ansible: How to iterate through the list of dictionaries using Jinja

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I get stuck and hope you can help me

I want to build file based on the following yml file with vars:

```
---
users:
   - name: "user1"
     db:
      - name: "main"
        default_privileges:
          tables: ['ALL']
          sequences: ['ALL']
          functions: ['EXECUTE']
          types: ['USAGE']
        schema:
          - name: "public"
            owner: no 
            default_privileges:
              tables: ['ALL']
              sequences: ['ALL']
              functions: ['EXECUTE']
              types: ['USAGE']
          - name: "notpublic"
            owner: no
            default_privileges:
              tables: ['ALL']
              sequences: ['ALL']
              functions: ['EXECUTE']
              types: ['USAGE']
              
   - name: "user2"
     db:
      - name: "main2"
        default_privileges:
          tables: ['ALL']
          sequences: ['ALL']
          functions: ['EXECUTE']
          types: ['USAGE']
        schema:
          - name: "public"
            owner: no 
            default_privileges:
              tables: ['ALL']
              sequences: ['ALL']
              functions: ['EXECUTE']
              types: ['USAGE']
          - name: "nonpublic"
            owner: no
            default_privileges:
              tables: ['ALL']
              sequences: ['ALL']
              functions: ['EXECUTE']
              types: ['USAGE']
```

How can I iterate through declared schema list in the Jinja template?
If I'm using the following construct

```
{% for user in users %}
{% for userdb in user.db %}
{% for s in userdb.schema %}

{{ s.name }}

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I get the following error during the execution:
`FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'schema'"}`

Comment: Debug the `users` object somewhere in you playbook before creating your file from template because, based on @JGK answer below, it obviously does not contain what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following playbook `f.yml`

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    users:
       - name: "user1"
         db:
          - name: "main"
            default_privileges:
              tables: ['ALL']
              sequences: ['ALL']
              functions: ['EXECUTE']
              types: ['USAGE']
            schema:
              - name: "public"
                owner: no
                default_privileges:
                  tables: ['ALL']
                  sequences: ['ALL']
                  functions: ['EXECUTE']
                  types: ['USAGE']
              - name: "notpublic"
                owner: no
                default_privileges:
                  tables: ['ALL']
                  sequences: ['ALL']
                  functions: ['EXECUTE']
                  types: ['USAGE']

       - name: "user2"
         db:
          - name: "main2"
            default_privileges:
              tables: ['ALL']
              sequences: ['ALL']
              functions: ['EXECUTE']
              types: ['USAGE']
            schema:
              - name: "public"
                owner: no
                default_privileges:
                  tables: ['ALL']
                  sequences: ['ALL']
                  functions: ['EXECUTE']
                  types: ['USAGE']
              - name: "nonpublic"
                owner: no
                default_privileges:
                  tables: ['ALL']
                  sequences: ['ALL']
                  functions: ['EXECUTE']
                  types: ['USAGE']


  tasks:
  - name: templating
    template:
      src: "f.jj"
      dest: "f.txt"
```

with this template `f.jj`

```
{% for user in users %}
{% for userdb in user.db %}
{% for s in userdb.schema %}

{{  s.name }}

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

produces with

```
$ ansible-playbook f.yml

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [templating] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

the output file `f.txt`

```
public


notpublic


public


nonpublic
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I dont undestand what is wrong then. What ansible and python version have you installed on your machine?

Comment: ansible 2.7.7 & python 3.7.3 on Debian Buster 10.4. Check your files, if there are some strange characters in. Copy & paste my example and diff it with your files.

Comment: Yep, that's the reason - special character. Previously, I've been also confused by several YAML validators - all said there are no errors. Thanks for helping!